# Перенаправление страницы после проверки формы

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django, валидация

Пытаюсь сделать панель регистрации в django. Не понимаю как сделать перенаправление страницы **после** проверки формы. Перенаправляет сразу же в /home/ без нее.
forms.py:

```
from django import forms
class Gen_info_form(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Bot</title>
    <style>
    .field{font-weight:bold;}
    .error{color:red;}
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="container">
    <form method="POST" id="form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
        {{ form }}
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Регистрация" id="reg" >
    </form>
    
<script>  
    $("#reg").click(function pageRedirect() {
      window.location.href = "/home/";
    });
</script>
</html>
```

1. Как сделать чтобы перенаправляло после валидации?
2. В чем разница использования между формами django и прописанными формами в html?

Comment: покажи свой файл views.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в чем разница между формами прописанными в html и django формами

1. в django формы используются для того, что бы описать все поля(название, типы значений, виджеты), которые нужны для ввода. Соответственно на основе этих данных в дальнейшем формируется html
2. Дальше после ввода пользователя, джанго использует формы для проверки введенных значений. Т.е. в форме прописываются правила, которые определяют верны ли значения введенные пользователем, или нет. Если данные не верны, то форма формирует соответствующее сообщение об ошибках.
3. Следующим этапом развития формы в джанго является форма модели `ModelForm`, которая автоматически формирует (1) пункт из описанного выше на основании описания Вашей модели, + так же частично(а в некоторых случаях полностью) реализует (2) пункт

Зачем использоваться формами джанго, если можно просто в html прописать все, что требуется?

1. Добавляя какое-то значение в html мы часто  должны будем править `.py` код для проверки введенных значений
2. Формы джанго можно использовать много раз на разных страницах
3. От Форм джанго как и от любого объекта можно наследоваться и добавлять какие-то дополнительные правила необходимые в том или ином случае

обычно твоя работа с формами будет выглядеть таким образом:
у тебя есть `View` в джанго, который отображает текущую страницу с формой. (Данный пример для использования function based view)

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import render
...

def my_form_view(request):
    if request.POST:
        my_form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if my_form.is_valid(): # Проверяем данные формы на корректность введенных значений
            #делаем требуемые операции, дальше перенаправляем пользователя на нужную страницу
            return HttpResponseRedirect("СТРАНИЦА_НА_КОТОРУЮ_НУЖНО_ПЕРЕНАПРАВИТЬ")
            # так же обычно СТРАНИЦА_НА_КОТОРУЮ_НУЖНО_ПЕРЕНАПРАВИТЬ не прописывается жестко, а используется reverse("name"), где name название страница из файла `urls.py` подробней можно прочитать на странице документации https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#module-django.urls.conf
    else:
        my_form = MyForm()
    return render(request, "требуемый_шаблон.html", {
        "form": my_form
    })
)
```

как ты видишь в данном коде не важно какие именно правила для формы мы прописываем, логика работы не меняется. И все изменения по форме которые нам придется вносить будут располагаться в одном месте в форме джанго в классе `MyForm()`